# Add custom video advert before YouTube video embedded on my site

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I would like to play custom video advert before YouTube video embedded in my site. I would like to play this advertisements before videos which was created by me located on my YouTube channel. I try to find some ways to do this on dfp portal but there is nothing. I also look for some JS code which can do something like this but without success. Is there any way how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with a video element, but some quick research tells me its attributes include `poster`, `autoplay`, and `onend`, and it has a `source` element (which has its own `src` attribute) inside it.
So you could set `source.src` to your advert, set `poster` to an image representing your "actual" video, and set `onend` to a function that 1)replaces the source with the actual video and 2)adds the `autoplay` attribute (or triggers the start of the actual video by some other means.)

If your video is in an iframe, it would be similar, but you'd have to fake the poster attribute (possibly by overlaying an image on the iframe and attaching your listener to that.) And you might need to pass information between the iframe and the main page when it comes time to play the actual video (unless you wanted to use a setTimeout function and just assume the advert ends at the same time as you expect it to end.)

Finally, if the actual video needs an iframe but you're able to store the advert locally, then you could make a video element for the advert as mentioned and replace it with the iframe when the advert ends.

Comment: I added a sentence to the answer to point out that even if the actual video is in an iframe, you can still get the benefits of the video element if the advert is stored on your server.